# What is the preferred way to pause an AIR-for-mobile app?

Tags: flash, mobile, air

I have made a Flash Air game. While playing it, if I press the Home button on my Android device, I get to the phone's menu yet I still get to listen to the game's music, which means that the game still keeps on fully working.

I would like my app to pause when not in the foreground. I have thought of this:

...

```
        stage.addEventListener(flash.events.Event.DEACTIVATE, deactivated);
```

...

```
    private function deactivated(e:flash.events.Event):void {
        delayedCall = new DelayedCall(quitNow, 2 * 60);
        stage.addEventListener(flash.events.Event.ACTIVATE, reactivated);
    }
    private function quitNow():void {
        NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
    }
    private function reactivated(e:flash.events.Event):void {
        stage.removeEventListener(flash.events.Event.ACTIVATE, reactivated);
        if (delayedCall) {
            delayedCall.dismiss();
            delayedCall = null;
        }
    }
```

...

where DelayedCall is a custom "wait-before-calling-this-function" class:

```
package fanlib.utils {
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

public class DelayedCall {

    private var data:*;
    private var callback:Function;
    private var timer:Timer;

    public function DelayedCall(callb:Function, seconds:Number, dat:* = undefined, count:int = 1) {
        callback = callb;
        data = dat;

        timer = new Timer(seconds * 1000, count);
        timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timeEvent);
        timer.start();
    }

    public function dismiss():void {
        timer.stop();
        complete();
    }

    private function timeEvent(e:TimerEvent):void {
        if (data) callback(data); else callback();
        if (timer.currentCount == timer.repeatCount) complete();
    }

    private function complete():void {
        timer = null;
        data = undefined;
    }
}
}
```

The method above works just fine with the Air Desktop version. When the window gets out-of-focus, the app quits after 2*60 seconds.

**On Android, the behavior is VERY peculiar:**

- quitNow() is never called by delayedCall
- if I remove "stage.addEventListener(flash.events.Event.ACTIVATE, reactivated);", then the app will close if I get back to it AFTER 2*60 seconds, but it won't close if I don't get back to it!!!

This seems like Actionscript code DOES get paused when the app is not in foreground, but the music plays on anyway.

Any ideas or better, an alternative, straightforward proved way? I don't intend to dig into Air's and Android's inner workings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android you can listen *NativeApplication*'s DEACTIVATE & ACTIVATE events. When the application is sent to background *handleApplicationDeactivated* will be called. And when it comes back *handleApplicationActivated* is called. Hope this helps.

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, handleApplicationDeactivated);
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, handleApplicationActivated);
```